# Deleting a row in a database using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, json, web

I am trying to deleting a row in my database by clicking a link in my PHP based web-page. All my database connections and table selections work well but while sending the primary key to the page that I am doing the delete operation it seem sthat I cannot send the right information since it is not deleting anything. Am I doing something wrong?

I am sending the information like this:

```
echo "<td><a href= 'delete.php?pid='{$_POST['id']}''> Delete </a></td>";
```

And deleting like this:

```
$del="DELETE FROM sca WHERE pid = '{$_POST['id']}'";
```

Thanks

Comment: yo dis code ain't safe

Comment: Please switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

If your delete query is on delete.php you want to access WHERE pid = '{$_GET['pid']}' from the URL as you will have lost your post data when clicking the link.

Comment: That is still unsafe.

Comment: I never said it was safe, I simply stated what was wrong with the query.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that "$_POST['id']" returns something?

```
echo '<td><a href="delete.php?pid=' . $_POST['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
```

You have to use $_GET variable there:

```
$id  = (int) $_GET['id'];
$del = "DELETE FROM `sca` WHERE `pid` = $id";
```

Comment: How do you know that `$id` can be cast to an integer?